# Is it possible to write a Linux daemon using Swift?

Tags: swift, linux, swift3, daemon

Swift is [available on Linux](https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift), and I am planing to give it a try. I was wondering though if it would be possible to write a daemon using that language. According to this [tutorial](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html), the steps involved are:

- Fork off the parent process
- Change file mode mask (umask)
- Open any logs for writing
- Create a unique Session ID (SID)
- Change the current working directory to a safe place
- Close standard file descriptors
- Enter actual daemon code

The two main things I am worrying about is how to fork off the parent process, and change the file mode mask in Swift.